# Next.js Redirects in next.config.js dynamicly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, next.js, config

I want to update Redirects routes after build of project. So, we have a redirect routes on BE Api.

I want to get it and implement to next.config.js dynamicly, here what i tried to do.

```
const getUrls = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(fetch("https://api.mocki.io/v1/a0b7f0b0").then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
          }).then(function(data) {
            return data.data;
          }) ), 3000);
    });

    // ExampleResponse = {
    //     "data":[
    //         {
    //             "source":"/test",
    //             "permanent":true,
    //             "destination":"/internet-application"
    //         }
    //     ]
    // }
    
module.exports = {
    poweredByHeader: false,
    async redirects() {
        return getUrls();
      },
}
```

Is there any solution to do it like that. I just want to update redirects from database.If the database update can we trigger redirects without stop project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically generate the redirect paths at *build time*, the problem in your code is that you need to `await` for the `getUrls` promise to resolve.

```js
module.exports = {
    poweredByHeader: false,
    async redirects() {
        return await getUrls();
    }
}
```

You can also simplify `getUrls` to not use `setTimeout` at all.

However, if you want to update the redirects at *runtime* you'll have to setup your own [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) for that.

Comment: +1 thank you for your answer. But i have to rebuild project to get updated json from url. I need to trigger redirects rools. For example when I call /refreshRoutes path I need to implement new redirect.json to project so it always updated by api. I don't want to bıild project each time because project deployed on server. I hope i am cleared my stuation.

Comment: Since the introduction of [Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) in Next.js v12, it's possible to setup dynamic redirects at runtime. See [How to have dynamic redirect URLs in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72810381/how-to-have-dynamic-redirect-urls-in-next-js).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can dynamically generate the redirect paths at build time, like this.

```
 const getRedirects = async () => {
  const url = `https://${domain}/redirects`;
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",       
  });
  const redirects = await res.json();
  return redirects
};
```

Now in next config object pass:

```
  async redirects() {
    return await getRedirects();
  },
```

make sure returned list of object be like:

```
{
    "source":"/test",
    "permanent":true,
    "destination":"/internet-application"
}
```